# How To Dynamically Use User Input for Jira Python

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

So I am trying to make an interactive method of pulling out Jira information, based on a Jira Key.

Full Code:

```py
import os
from atlassian import Jira

import json
with open('secrets.json','r') as f:
      config = json.load(f)

jira_instance = Jira(
    url = "https://mirantis.jira.com",
    username = (config['user']['username']),
    password = (config['user']['password'])
)

projects = jira_instance.get_all_projects(included_archived=None)

value = input("Please enter your Jira Key and the Issue ID:\n")
jira_key = (value)

issue = jira_instance.issue('(jira_key)', fields='summary,history,created,updated')
#issue = jira_instance.issue('DESDI-212', fields='summary,history,created,updated')
print(issue)
```

The main thing that is breaking is this:

```py
issue = jira_instance.issue('(jira_key)', fields='summary,history,created,updated')
```

For some odd reason, it doesn't like the way I am using user input for `jira_key` even though it will print out what I want if I use `print(jira_key)`

Am I invoking it wrong?

I basically need this:

```
issue = jira_instance.issue('DESDI-212', fields='summary,history,created,updated')
```

Whereby which, DESDI-212 will be user input.
When I try it using `'(jira_key)'` it responds back with this error:

```sh
 rbarrett@MacBook-Pro-2  ~/Projects/Mirantis/Dataeng/Python  python test_single.py                                                             ✔  10422  22:03:34
Please enter your Jira Key and the Issue ID:
DESDI-212
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rbarrett/Projects/Mirantis/Dataeng/Python/test_single.py", line 19, in <module>
    issue = jira_instance.issue('(jira_key)', fields='summary,history,created,updated')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/atlassian/jira.py", line 676, in issue
    return self.get("rest/api/2/issue/{0}?fields={1}".format(key, fields), params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/atlassian/rest_client.py", line 264, in get
    response = self.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/atlassian/rest_client.py", line 236, in request
    self.raise_for_status(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/atlassian/jira.py", line 3715, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(error_msg, response=response)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: Issue does not exist or you do not have permission to see it.
```

I expect to see this, which if I use `'DESDI-212'` instead of `'(jira_key)'` it actually works:

```sh
{'expand': 'renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations', 'id': '372744', 'self': 'https://mirantis.jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/372744', 'key': 'DESDI-212', 'fields': {'summary': 'Add the MSR version to be parsed into Loadstone', 'updated': '2021-06-23T17:33:21.206-0700', 'created': '2021-06-01T12:54:06.136-0700'}}
```

Comment: why are you quoting `jira_key`? You shuold just need to change that one line to `jira_instance.issue(jira_key, fields='summary,history,created,updated')`

Comment: I was getting confused thinking I needed to use the `''` around it as IO was specifying the key as a literal string earlier. In any event with and without parenthesis works thanks a bunch @joshmeranda

Comment: Sounds good, simple mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I was invoking it wrong.
I needed to drop the `''` around the `'(jira_key)'` and just invoke it as follows with `(jira_key)` instead:

```py
import os
from atlassian import Jira

import json
with open('secrets.json','r') as f:
      config = json.load(f)

jira_instance = Jira(
    url = "https://mirantis.jira.com",
    username = (config['user']['username']),
    password = (config['user']['password'])
)

projects = jira_instance.get_all_projects(included_archived=None)

value = input("Please enter your Jira Key and the Issue ID:\n")
jira_key = (value)

issue = jira_instance.issue((jira_key), fields='summary,history,created,updated')
#issue = jira_instance.issue('DESDI-212', fields='summary,history,created,updated')
print(issue)
```

As such I got the expected output I needed, not it's working as expected:

```sh
 rbarrett@MacBook-Pro-2  ~/Projects/Mirantis/Dataeng/Python  python test_single.py                                                             ✔  10428  22:22:17
Please enter your Jira Key and the Issue ID:
DESDI-212
{'expand': 'renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations', 'id': '372744', 'self': 'https://mirantis.jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/372744', 'key': 'DESDI-212', 'fields': {'summary': 'Add the MSR version to be parsed into Loadstone', 'updated': '2021-06-23T17:33:21.206-0700', 'created': '2021-06-01T12:54:06.136-0700'}}
```